# Hosting dota on garena using hostbot

Tags: dota

Can anyone Please guide me on how to host dota on garena using hostbot along with the settings to reduce lag/delay...Is there another way to host?

Comment: so you want to know how to host dota games generally (garena does not need to be used if there is something easier?)?

in that case i would recommend GHost One which is is the most used tool for hosting games in bnet without much lag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the latest version of **Garena HostBot** which is very easy to setup and adjust according to your network speed, you can get it from:
http://www.garenaworld.com/Forum-Garena-HostBot

But If you want a more advance version of the hostbot then you should try **Ghost++ One**.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, can you elaborate on that please? Citing from the relevant forum post could be an option..